# Copy text directly to clipboard in asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core

I want the value I clicked on the event to be saved in the clipboard but this code does not work please see where my mistake is

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-warning" onclick="navigator.clipboard.writeText(@Model.projectCode)">@Model.projectCode</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use function below to copy element in clipboard

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-warning" onclick="copyToClipboard('@Model.projectCode')">@Model.projectCode</button>

function copyToClipboard(element) {
     var $temp = $("<input>");
     $("body").append($temp);
     $temp.val(element).select();
     document.execCommand("copy");
     $temp.remove();
}
```

Comment: how i can use it?

Comment: Answer Updated, Please check

Comment: My friend, did you test this code? It did not work for me

Comment: Hi Dear, yes it's tested try to open console and paste function as is, after that call it and finally ctrl + p and you'll find that it works